# Rererence native dll

Tags: .net

I have a pinvoke wrapper of some native dll. Both wrapper and dll are located in Libraries in my solution folder. I can add .NET wrapper as reference to the project but what should I do to make native dll available in output folder? For now I just copied it manually, but I am pretty sure there a more appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you could include it as part of the project and in the properties window set the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`. This will copy the native library to the output folder (`Debug` or `Release`) based on the mode you are targeting. If this is an ASP.NET application you might need to deploy the native library into some system folder which is part of the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Set the "Copy to Output Directory" property as "Always" in the property window.

Comment: That's a lot of needless copying, "Copy if newer" is the appropriate choice.